# Get Refill time of Fuel from a given table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table in which fuel fill up details are given we have id column then fuel_in_ltr column which tell us that how much fuel we have and then we TIME column which tell us that at a particular time how much fuel we have.

```
create table fuel_details (id number, fuel_in_ltr number, time timestamp);  

insert into fuel_details values (1, 10, '24-jan-2017 12:00');  
insert into fuel_details values (2, 9, '24-jan-2017 01:00');  
insert into fuel_details values (3, 8, '24-jan-2017 02:00');  
insert into fuel_details values (4, 7, '24-jan-2017 03:00');  
insert into fuel_details values (5, 12, '24-jan-2017 04:00');  
insert into fuel_details values (6, 11, '24-jan-2017 05:00');  
insert into fuel_details values (7, 10, '24-jan-2017 06:00');  
insert into fuel_details values (8, 13, '24-jan-2017 07:00');  
insert into fuel_details values (9, 12, '24-jan-2017 08:00');  
insert into fuel_details values (10, 11, '24-jan-2017 09:00');  
insert into fuel_details values (11, 10, '24-jan-2017 10:00');  
insert into fuel_details values (12, 13, '24-jan-2017 11:00');
```

Here in above INSERT statement we can see that at 12 PM we have 10 ltr fuel then at 1 PM we have 9 ltr and at 2 PM 8 ltr as so on but at 4 PM we have 12 ltr of fuel that means we REFILLED our FUEL at 4PM so from above table we need to get the time of EACH refiling happens !

My DB is -
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Don't use strings to insert timestamps (or dates) and rely on implicit conversion - instead you should use `TO_TIMESTAMP()` specifying the format mask or use an ANSI timestamp literal - i.e. `TIMESTAMP '2017-01-24 00:00:00'`.

Comment: I will remember in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LAG` analytic function:

```
SELECT id, time
FROM   (
  SELECT f.*,
         LAG( fuel_in_ltr ) OVER ( ORDER BY time, id ) AS prev_fuel_in_ltr
  FROM   fuel_details f
)
WHERE  fuel_in_ltr > prev_fuel_in_ltr;
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks I need more studies :)

Comment: @mradul Question, what happens if between the timestamps we fill up say 5 liters, but use 10? Would that fill up then be missed?

Comment: @BobC The OP's question shows a steady hourly usage rate of `1` liter per hour. If we know this then the query could be changed to `WHERE fuel_in_ltr > prev_fuel_in_ltr - :hourly_usage`. However, this would not make sense where the unit has to be turned off for an hour to refuel or if there is a dynamic amount of fuel used per hour so a certain amount of domain knowledge would have to be applied.